Looking for proteins that play a role in cardiovascular diseases (disease ontology)
I'm looking for proteins that (probably) play a role in cardiovascular diseases. I have to compile a list of them. It's recommended to use The Disease Ontology. But if I'm correct this specific protein information is not imported into the database.  Could someone suggest how to use Disease Ontology for this purpose? Or, failing this, is there another tool or resource I can use for this purpose?
Cross posted:

https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/22911/looking-for-proteins-play-role-in-cardiovascular-diseases-disease-ontology
https://www.biostars.org/p/9602811/


I see that you have crossposted this question to biostars and bioinformatics SE. In such cases it is considered polite to link your questions to each other, so that we don't spend a lot of time answering a question that's already been answered.

"Cardiovascular disease" is a very big topic, it involves a large number of biological processes. I think you may need to get more specific.
I would suggest relying on Gene Ontology, which has protein annotations for various biological structures, processes, etc.
One approach would be to try to link between Disease Ontology and Gene Ontology using for example MeSH terms, to which both seem to have mappings.
As another approach, you might focus on whatever specific disease you find interesting, look for its etiology (possibly using disease ontology or even just review papers), and use that to look things up on Gene Ontology.
